# How can I compute the confidence level in the approximate randomization test?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, permutation-test

(1) indicates that one can compute a confidence level from the approximate randomization test (step 4):

[image]

However, (1) simply refers to (2) to view the actual calculation or table lookup. Unfortunately, I don't have access to (2). How can I compute the confidence level in the approximate randomization test?

---

1. Chinchor, Nancy. "The statistical significance of the MUC-4 results." In Proceedings of the 4th conference on Message understanding, pp. 30-50. Association for Computational Linguistics, 1992. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9100345284812509896&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5
2. Noreen, E. W. (1989) Computer Intensive Methods for Testing Hypotheses: An Introduction. New York." John Wiley & Sons. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9751452310612539454&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

Comment: I don't understand point #4 in the reproduced Table. What table lookup are they talking about?! (Also, please replace appr-rand with permutation-test as per my other comment.)

Comment: @amoeba I'm not sure, I am also looking for this table :-)

Comment: I think point #4 is meaningless. What is "confidence level" anyway?  "Significance level" from point #3 is simply p-value.